# Row в bootstrap не выравнивается по-средине строки

Tags: html5

```css
    .wrapper {
        max-width: 1180px;
    }
    
    .container-fluid {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    header .logo a {
        color: #00c853;
        font-size: 32px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    header .nav ul {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    header .nav ul li {
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    header .nav ul li a {
        color: #000;
        padding-right: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    header .nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }
    
    header .tel {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000;
    }
    
    header .tel i {
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <header>
     <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
       <div class="col-lg-auto logo">
        <a href="#">Logo</a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-auto nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-auto tel">
        <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
        +38(111)111-11-11
        <button>Перезвонить</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`align-items-center` работает, у списка меню нужно обнулить `margin/margin-bottom`. Так как из за этого высота блока `nav` больше и вам кажется, что нет выравнивания.

Comment: Добавил margin-bottom: 0 в li все равно nav выше

Comment: @Mighty, `li` это елемент списка, а `ul` это список, вот у него и нужно обнулить `margin`

Comment: Да, спасибо помогло, но теперь новая проблема в gulp ошибку выбивает когда пишу margin-bottom: Invalid CSS after " marging: 0px": expected "{", was ""

Comment: @Mighty, значит у вас ошибка в стилях. В ошибке скорее всего указан файл где и даже номер строки

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lat6z1 Оно то пишет, но я не могу найти решение этой проблемы. Один из вариантов, которые я нашел это поменять расширение файла с .sass та .scss, но думаю есть другие способы решения. Прошу прощение, что задалбываю вопросами.

Comment: @Mighty, вы если хотите показать код, то залейте его на codepen или jsfiddle и показывайте весь.

Answer (score 0):

Выравниваетсья .

У вас в среднем блоке стоит классы **col-lg-auto nav**

Также в других блоках стоит

**col-lg-auto tel** и **col-lg-auto logo**

Проблема в том что вот этот `nav` которое стоит рядом с `col-lg-auto` это имя бустраповского класса если изменить его на что нибудь другое у вас будет семантически правильная верстка и имена классов не будут конфликтовать.

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1180px;
}

.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
}

header .logo a {
    color: #00c853;
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header .navigation-center ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

header .navigation-center ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

header .navigation-center ul li a {
    color: #000;
    padding-right: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

header .navigation-center ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

header .tel {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}

header .tel i {
    padding-right: 5px;[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-lg-auto logo">
                <a href="#">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-auto navigation-center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-auto tel">
                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                +38(111)111-11-11
                <button>Перезвонить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Поменял nav на navline - все равно не помогло(